# Is Introduce constant missing from Resharper 8.2 C# edition?

Tags: resharper

I have Introduce Field, Parameter, Variable, Variable for substring and Move to resource. But no Introduce Constant. Is it missing or am I just not seeing it?

(I believe I rember there have being such a (n obvious) choice from an earlier version.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an option in the introduce field and variable refactorings. An introduce constant would need to know where you wanted to introduce it - either as a field or variable. Makes sense to roll it into the field and variable refactor workflows.

[image]